# how to return certain fields in a mongoose nodejs request

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I wrote such a request.below is the request code.

```
await Room
    .findOne({ _id: id_room })
    .populate('messages.author','username')
    .select('messages.message')
    .then((rooms =>{
    return res.status(200).json({
      rooms
    });
  })).catch((error)=>{
    return res.status(500).json({
      message:error.message,error
    });
  });
```

here is the data that is returned to me after the request.

```
{

    "rooms": {
        "_id": "62c6e2f552d6718f6aea01f4",
        "messages": [
            {
                "message": "hi",
                "author": {
                    "_id": "62c6d43d6c5c2aebdc575019",
                    "username": "vadim"
                }
            },
            {
                "message": "hi",
                "author": {
                    "_id": "62c7faf8ef9176ea1b6dbd57",
                    "username": "oleg"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

how do I change the query to get data like

```
{
    "rooms": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "message": "hi",
                "author": "vadim"
            },
            {
                "message": "hi",
                "author" "oleg"
            
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

if I write the request like this `.select('messages.message message.author')`,without `populate` . then I get the output I need. But id is output instead of username.

Comment: You can pass the fields you want to select in ```populate``` like, ```populate('author', 'name')```

Comment: @vicki I did so.  but in the output I also get the id

Comment: Try this, ```populate({model: 'author', select: 'name  -_id',})```. Note that, there is a minus sign before id field. I'm not sure if it is ```model: 'author'``` or ```path: 'author'```. but try with either one of these.

Comment: @vicki yes, it helped. now I get the following  data `"author": {
                "username": "vadim"
            }`

can I somehow get only the username value in the author. `"author":"vadim"`

Comment: I think, it would involve manual parsing to modify it like the way you want. I'll try if it is possible in mongoose.